# Scraping a worksheet for data and pasting to a separate worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

This short script breaks at 'Next'. I'd like to save this data in a collection so i can dump and customize how it's presented across the workbook. Thanks for your help

Edit: Updated my code. Still running into issues.

Resource Class

```
''''''''''''''''''''''
' Name property
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property
Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
    pName = Value
End Property

''''''''''''''''''''''
' City property
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get City() As String
    City = pCity
End Property
Public Property Let City(Value As String)
    pCity = Value
End Property

''''''''''''''''''''''
' Title property
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get Title() As String
    Title = pTitle
End Property
Public Property Let Title(Value As String)
    pTitle = Value
End Property
```

The script

```
    Sub searchResources()


Dim a As Range
Dim cell As Variant
Dim Resources As Collection
Dim Emp As Resource
Dim Count As Integer




For Each cell In a.Rows
    If cell.Value = "Dallas" Or cell.Value = "Oklahoma City" Or cell.Value = "Houston" Then
    Set Emp = New Resource
        Emp.City = cell.Value
        cell.Offset(0, -2).Select
        Emp.Title = cell.Value
        cell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        Emp.Name = cell.Value
            Resources.Add Emp


                  End If

Resume Next

For Each Emp In Resources

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("A").Activate
a.Select
    Debug.Print Emp.Name
    Debug.Print Emp.City
    Debug.Print Emp.Title
Next Emp

End Sub
```

Comment: where are the exact error, your script looks not perfect

Comment: @Never_Mind "Next without for"

Comment: So. you have found the answer by your self isn'tit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For Each cell In a.Rows
    If cell.Value = "Dallas" Then
    Set Emp = New Resource
        Emp.City = cell.Value
        cell.Offset(0, -2).Select
        Emp.Title = cell.Value
        cell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        Emp.Name = cell.Value
            Resources.Add Emp

            >> Resume Next

    ElseIf cell.Value = "Oklahoma City" Then
    Set Emp = New Resource
        Emp.City = cell.Value
        cell.Offset(0, -2).Select
        Emp.Title = cell.Value
        cell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        Emp.Name = cell.Value
            Resources.Add Emp

           >> Resume Next

    ElseIf cell.Value = "Houston" Then
    Set Emp = New Resource
        Emp.City = cell.Value
       cell.Offset(0, -2).Select
        Emp.Title = cell.Value
        cell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        Emp.Name = cell.Value
            Resources.Add Emp

         >> Resume  Next

            End If
>>> Next

For Each Emp In Resources

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("A").Activate
a.Select
    Debug.Print Emp.Name
    Debug.Print Emp.City
    Debug.Print Emp.Title
Next Emp

End If <<<Why here have end if? i think you should delete it, cause it doesnt have IF stand for it


UPDATE
```

I think your script got too long and not need to repeat at the same

```
For Each cell In a.Rows
    If cell.Value = "Dallas" or cell.Value = "Oklahoma City" or cell.Value = "Houston" Then
    Set Emp = New Resource
        Emp.City = cell.Value
        cell.Offset(0, -2).Select
        Emp.Title = cell.Value
        cell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        Emp.Name = cell.Value
            Resources.Add Emp
                  End If
else
'based on you want to EXIT FOR or RESUME NEXT
Next

For Each Emp In Resources

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("A").Activate
a.Select
    Debug.Print Emp.Name
    Debug.Print Emp.City
    Debug.Print Emp.Title
Next Emp
```

Comment: Have you checked your code? Is it workable? Note the extra line before comment (`else` <--- why?)..........

Comment: O yeah, that is for him if need in another statements, he can delete it too if not to be used

Answer (score 2):

I Modified the CLass slightly (Added the private variables, and corrected the proc. In the proc I used 'Selected Cells' as my range variable, I don't know how you intended to pass that. I also have it create a new sheet, and added a small bit of code to ensure the sheet name we give it is unique.

The Class:

```
Private pName As String
Private pCity As String
Private pTitle As String

''''''''''''''''''''''
' Name property
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property
Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
    pName = Value
End Property

''''''''''''''''''''''
' City property
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get City() As String
    City = pCity
End Property
Public Property Let City(Value As String)
    pCity = Value
End Property

''''''''''''''''''''''
' Title property
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get Title() As String
    Title = pTitle
End Property
Public Property Let Title(Value As String)
    pTitle = Value
End Property
```

And the Procedure:

```
Sub searchResources()
Dim a As Range
Dim cell As Range 'As Variant (This is a range)
Dim Resources As Collection
Dim Emp As Resource
Dim Count As Integer
'---------
Dim oWS As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Integer, iTest As Integer
Set Resources = New Collection

'Setting the range to selected range on active sheet for my tests
'Assign your range as you see fit
Set a = Application.Selection


For Each cell In a.Cells
    If cell.Value = "Dallas" Or cell.Value = "Oklahoma City" Or cell.Value = "Houston" Then
    Set Emp = New Resource

        Emp.City = cell.Value
        Emp.Title = cell.Offset(0, -2).Value
        Emp.Name = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        Resources.Add Emp
    End If
Next cell

Set oWS = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))

'create a unique name
iRow = 1
On Error Resume Next 'Turn on error handling
iTest = Len(Worksheets("Resources").Name)
'check for error
If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'Sheet doesn't exist
    oWS.Name = "Resources"
Else
    Do
        iTest = Len(Worksheets("Resources" & iRow).Name)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            oWS.Name = "Resources" & iRow
            Exit Do
        Else
            iRow = iRow + 1
        End If
        DoEvents 'Allows CTRL-BREAK to break execution during the cycle
    Loop
End If
On Error GoTo 0 'Turn off error handling
iRow = 2
oWS.Range("A1").Value = "Name"
oWS.Range("B1").Value = "Title"
oWS.Range("C1").Value = "City"

For Each Emp In Resources
    oWS.Range("A" & iRow) = Emp.Name
    oWS.Range("C" & iRow) = Emp.City
    oWS.Range("B" & iRow) = Emp.Title
    iRow = iRow + 1
Next Emp

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you use `Resume Next` where you should use `Next cell` please see corrected code bellow:

```
Sub searchResources()


Dim a As Range
Dim cell As Variant
Dim Resources As Collection
Dim Emp As Resource
Dim Count As Integer




For Each cell In a.Rows
    If cell.Value = "Dallas" Or cell.Value = "Oklahoma City" Or cell.Value = "Houston" Then
    Set Emp = New Resource
        Emp.City = cell.Value
        cell.Offset(0, -2).Select
        Emp.Title = cell.Value
        cell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        Emp.Name = cell.Value
            Resources.Add Emp


                  End If

Next cell

For Each Emp In Resources

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("A").Activate
a.Select
    Debug.Print Emp.Name
    Debug.Print Emp.City
    Debug.Print Emp.Title
Next Emp

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

running your code though a beautifier gives me a hint: there is no `Next cell` corresponding to the `For Each cell In a.Rows`

The beautifier can be found [here](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Indenter/Default.htm). (The web site only shows up to Office 2003, but I have tested it in 2007 and 2010, and it works perfectly)

The resultant code after beautifying:

```
Sub searchResources()

Dim a As Range
Dim cell As Variant
Dim Resources As Collection
Dim Emp As Resource
Dim Count As Integer

For Each cell In a.Rows
    If cell.Value = "Dallas" Or cell.Value = "Oklahoma City" Or cell.Value = "Houston" Then
        Set Emp = New Resource
        Emp.City = cell.Value
        cell.Offset(0, -2).Select
        Emp.Title = cell.Value
        cell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        Emp.Name = cell.Value
        Resources.Add Emp


    End If

    Resume Next

    For Each Emp In Resources

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("A").Activate
        a.Select
Debug.Print Emp.Name
Debug.Print Emp.City
Debug.Print Emp.Title
    Next Emp

    End Sub
```

notice that the `End Sub` does not line up with the `Sub()` declaration